# Why elemen didn't create when it is drugguble EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I! buttons from my toolbar have to create panel.
And I have some problems, and questions.

1) when created panel is set druggable: true, panel didn't rents after click. And Chrome console throwns it: o such config "translationMethod" for class Ext.util.translatable.CssPosition. How to make it works (draggable)?

2)which the best way to create panel on the Main? like I do or another method?  I use extjs 6.2 modern.

3)when centered is false, panel created anomalously (without header and title). how to fix it?

Toolbar is one from items of Main. 'mycuts' button is one from toolbar's items.
I hope somebody can help me
There is code:

```
{
            text:'mycuts',
            cls: 'grbuttons',
            ui:'action',
            height: 35,
            width: 205,
            margin:2,


            handler: function() {

                Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
                    height: 300,
                    id:'mycutareagrid',
                    header:{
                        title:'cuts',
                        draggable: true,
                    },
                    //draggable:true,
                    header: {
                        cls : 'hdr2'

                    },
                    width: 850,
                    renderTo:'bighBox',
                    centered:true,
                    margin: '98 0 0 215',
                    autoDestroy: true,
                    items:[{
                        xtype:'contlistII'
                    }],
                    collapsible:true,
                    clossable: true,
                    scope: this, 
                    tools: [{
                            type:'help'
                            },{
                            type:'search'       
                            },{
                            type:'close',
                            handler: function(e) {

                                    e.hide()
                            }
                            }],

                    listeners:{
                          afterrender: function(e){
                              var d = e.getHeaderContainer();
                              e.setHeight(10);
                          }  
                        }


                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which is it? Ext4 or Ext6? Don't just randomly tag your questions.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Sorry! It 6.2 only.